# Test class for Visual Workflow

Tags: unit-test, visual-workflow

I have a flow, which shows a list of Opportunities, one by one based on score. This flow has been referenced on a Visualforce page:

```xml
   <apex:page controller="OppPriorityController">
    <h1>Opportunity Prioritisation Wokflow</h1>
    <flow:interview name="Opportunity_Prioritisation_Flow" interview="{!myflow}" buttonLocation="bottom">
     <apex:param name="varCurrentUserID" value="{!$User.Id}"/> 
    </flow:interview>
   </apex:page>
```

The OppPriorityController is below:

```
    public class OppPriorityController {
    
    public Flow.Interview.Opportunity_Prioritisation_Flow myflow { get; set; }
    public String getPhoneNumber() {
             return myflow.PhoneNumber; 
             }
    public String getAccountID() {
             return myflow.AccId;
    }
     public String getAccountName() {
             return myflow.AccountName;
    }
     public String getOpportunityID() {
             return myflow.OppId;
    }
     public String getOpportunityName() {
             return myflow.OppName;
    }
}
```

The test class which I tried is below:

```
    @isTest (SeeAllData=true)
private class OppPriorityControllerTest {
    public static testMethod void myTestMethodForFlow() {
        PageReference pageRef = Page.OppPriorityPage;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        OppPriorityController oppPriorityController = new OppPriorityController();        
        oppPriorityController.myflow = new Flow.Interview.Opportunity_Prioritisation_Flow(new Map<String, Object>());
        String pNumber = oppPriorityController.getPhoneNumber();
        String accountId = oppPriorityController.getAccountID() ;
        String accountName = oppPriorityController.getAccountName();
        String opportunityID = oppPriorityController.getOpportunityID();
        String opportunityName = oppPriorityController.getOpportunityName();
    }
}
```

I received an exception: **Interview not started.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now there is no real way to test the controller. You would need an Apex API for Flow to do this, which I am told is something we are working on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So basically we cannot 'start' the interview from apex class?
But there are few posts which have shown similar classes: http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/10/dynamic-visualforce-and-visual-workflow-with-rerender.html
http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visual-Workflow/Visual-Flow-inside-Visualforce-Page-with-Apex-Controller-Lag-in/m-p/483595#M681

None of them have the test class !!

Comment: Hahha, one of them is your own blog ;)

Comment: You can put a Flow in a Visualforce page with a controller, and get a reference to the Flow from Apex, but you can't 'drive' the Flow from Apex. Right now, the Flow can only be driven from the browser.

Comment: Hmm, I agree. I also referred this http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_flows_advanced.htm, and changed the apex code accordingly. But no use. As you said flow cannot be driven from apex. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

If the goal is track how changes might effect the user flow - you might try a Selenium script with it:

http://seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Nope, the goal is to start the interview from apex class. I believe it is started from VF page by the interview="{!myflow}" tag in: <flow:interview name="Opportunity_Prioritisation_Flow" interview="{!myflow}">