# Is it still impossible to start a Flow Interview for a VisualForce Controller's Unit Tests?

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, visual-workflow, custom-controller, flow

Currently looking at [An Advanced Example of Using](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_advanced.htm)

Been writing some unit tests for the VisualForce controllers I've been creating, which, with my original code would result in  "Interview not started" exceptions.

I did some googling and found this older (August 2012) salesforce.stackechange.com q&a ("[Test class for Visual Workflow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/562/test-class-for-visual-workflow)") whence @Metadaddy informed the OP:

> Right now there is no real way to test the controller. You would need an Apex API for Flow to do this, which I am told is something we are working on.

Using mocking, I was able to test 91% of my controller, but as a maximalist who is dubious about using mocking for tests, I'd much rather have higher and more direct coverage.

Does anyone know if there is an adequate Apex API for Flow, or any alternative solutions, to enable this yet?